# UICollectionView Cell with tick box in the image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        println(indexPath)
        cell.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        cell.frame.size.width = self.screenWidth / 3
        cell.frame.size.height = self.screenWidth / 3


        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as! String
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.getMediaFilePath(self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].pathToMedia))
        cell.imageTicked.hidden = true

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
        self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected  = true
        cell.selected = true
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected  = false
        cell.selected = false
    }
```

I can hide imageTicked in the function which is returning the cell but I cannot add it inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`.
I would like to show the tickbox when the item is selected and hide the tickbox when the item is deselected.

Just wondering how to set `cell.imageTicked.hidden = true` inside `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` and `cell.imageTicked.hidden = false` inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a selectedIndexPath variable. Set it in didSelectItemAtIndexPath and remove in didDeselectItemAtIndexPath. Remember to call reloadData() to reload collection view.

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?;
...         
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath){
   ...
   if selectedIndexPath != nil {
      cell.imageTicked.hidden = selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row
   }
   else {
      cell.imageTicked.hidden = true
   }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
   ...
   self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
   collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
  ...
  self.selectedIndexPath = nil
  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```